# Shared state in React updates the rest of the components and the current one as well

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have a use case where I have 4 select components all sharing the same state. The problem is when the user selects an option from one select, the other selects should not show that option and so on. That problem is simple and solved. On doing so I am updating the shared state and hence all 4 selects are re-rendered by react and hence I am losing the selected value from the select. See attached GIF.

Can someone point out a solution where I can solve this using minimum states and less re-rendering?

[image: Use Case Example]

Attaching the whole code below:

```
  const SendTroops = () => {
  const [planets, setPlanets] = useState([]);
  const [vehicles, setVehicles] = useState([]);

  const constructState = (data) => {
    const arr = [];
    let obj = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      obj[i] = data;
    }
    arr.push(obj);
    return arr;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPlanets = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await callAPI(PLANETS.url, PLANETS.method);
        const data = await response.json();
        setPlanets(constructState(data));
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }

    const getVehicles = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await callAPI(VEHICLES.url, VEHICLES.method);
        const data = await response.json();
        setVehicles(constructState(data));
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };

    getPlanets();
    getVehicles();

  }, []);

  const ShowInputs = (n) => {
    const options = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      options.push((
        <div className="column" key={i}>
          <Select
            styles="select"
            name={`destination${i}`}
            options={(planets && planets[0]) ? planets[0][i] : []}
            onSelect={(e) => onDestinationChange(e, i)} />
          <Radio
            styles="radio"
            name={`vehicle${i}`}
            options={(vehicles && vehicles[0]) ? vehicles[0][i] : []}
            onSelect={(e) => onVehicleChange(e, i)} />
        </div>
      ))
    }
    return options;
  }

  const onDestinationChange = (e, index) => {
    const selectedName = e.target.value;
    const values = Object.values(planets[0]);
    let obj = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if (i === index) obj[i] = values[i];
      else {
        obj[i] = values[i].filter((value) => value.name !== selectedName);
      }
    }
    const updatedPlanets = [].concat([obj]);
    setPlanets(updatedPlanets);
  };

  const onVehicleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };

  const onReset = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    < main >
      <p className="search-title">Select planets for your Troops to search</p>
      <form>
        <div className="row">
          {ShowInputs(4)}
        </div>
        <div className="row button-group">
          <Link to='/missionreport'>
            <Button styles="button" type="submit" text="Find Falcone" />
          </Link>
          <Button styles="button" type="reset" text="Reset" onPress={onReset} />
        </div>
      </form>
    </main >
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remember the index of selected planet in planets list and the index of `select` element where that planet has been chosen. Then show the selected option only on the `select` where it's been previously chosen.

That way you must add 2 more fields to your state:

1. Index of selected planet in planets list (let default be `-1` or something negative)
2. Index of `<select>` element where it's been chosen (in your case it's the iterator `i` of the `for` loop in `ShowInputs()`).

Then update that fields every time when the user selects something (using `onDestinationChange()`).